# Angular input form into *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm little confused about how I should work with Angular 2 when I need `<input>` tags inside the `<tr>` tags of a table, when the `<tr>` tags are generated by a `*ngFor`. My situation is this: I have an array of "products", I should show the product's info on `<tr>` tags and, for each product, an `input` field to increase the stock of each product. This is what I have done:

## ProductStokeComponent.ts

```
export class ProductStokeComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  products: Subject<Product[]> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formInit();
    this.getProducts();
  }

  formInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      products: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.products.next(data);
    });
  }

}
```

## ProductStokeComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Stock Entrance</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody formArrayName="products">
      <tr *ngFor="let product of products| async">
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.stock }}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="stock[product.id]" >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Add Stock</button>
</form>
```

On pure html, I was able to do away with a named array, but with Angular 2 I'm trying using a reactive form, but then I should use a for loop to fill the form after a loop to generate the table for each product, this sounds like using a lot of resources to do a simple thing.

**Update with methods reactive form**

**ProductStokeComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formInit();
    this.getProducts();
}

formInit(product?: Product) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      products: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
}
```

**ProductStokeComponent.html**

```
<tbody formArrayName="products">
```

Comment: The idea is to put in the `input` the number of elements to add to the stock?

Comment: yes, should be a input number

Answer (score 1):

The reactive solution looks like this:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let product of form.controls['products'].controls">
        <td>{{ product.value.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.value.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.value.stock }}</td>
        <td>
            <input #moreStock>
            <button (click)="addMoreStock(product.value, moreStock.value)">+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Or if you want the template forms solution:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.stock }}</td>
    <td>
      <input #moreStock>
      <button (click)="addMoreStock(product, moreStock.value)">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In both cases, in your TypeScript file add a method like this:

```
public addMoreStock(product, howMuch)
{
    product.stock += parseInt(howMuch, 10);
}
```

Comment: on this form i will are working with a propertie on object product, and what i will do with the reactive form, im using reactive or is not good idea work with reactive form on this case?

Comment: There are my problem, how i have the values of products on form.controls['products'].controls, i will fill all from a products array in the form, but will use just the new value of stock how input data